# el-select with multiple and object for value not showing text in tag

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, element-ui

I have read through all the questions here and still can't seem to understand why I am not getting any text in my tags.

I am using a  and an object for the value of the . When I close my dialog and reopen it, all my data is fetched from the backend and loaded inside the component. Just the tags in my multiple select are not showing the text. They have the right key, when I inspect them within the vue devtools, but they just show up empty.

Here is my code:

```js
<el-select
 v-model="defaultFilter.val"
 value-key="value"
 multiple
 size="mini"
 filterable
 remote
 :placeholder="'Aktiv-/Passivfilter Wert für ' + obj.label"
 :remote-method="remoteMethod"
 :loading="configOptions.loading"
>
 <el-option-group v-for="group in configOptions.options" :key="group.label" :label="group.label">
   <el-option v-for="item in group.options" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" :value="item">
      <span style="float: left">{{ item.label }}</span>
      <span v-if="item.description" style="padding-left: 5px; color: #8492a6; font-size: 9px">{{
                              item.description
                            }}</span>
    </el-option>
  </el-option-group>
</el-select>
```

I have read through the documentation and just don't understand what I am doing wrong here. The item I am passing to value in my el-option looks like this:

```json
{
 description: "ABC",
 filterProp: "abc",
 label: "A B C",
 value: "ABC"
}
```

In my tags inside the select, I want to show the value text. Am I missing some config or setting?

I am using `"element-ui": "^2.13.2",` and `"vue": "2.6.10",`

Help or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in code you shared. Probably something is wrong in your methods or data.
And I will guess here because you didn't share full code.

If you followed their documentation with your data then you probably stuck because you have array of objects and they have array of strings.
That is this part from [their example](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) and what you need is `item.value` and `item.label` instead of `item`:

```
mounted() {
  this.list = this.states.map(item => {
    // here you need item.value and item.label
    return { value: `value:${item}`, label: `label:${item}` };
  });
}
```

But this is just an example and here you probably get data from API so you need to check how that data is structured.

Here is full working example with your data https://codepen.io/jakob_/pen/GRxMQQN